# Gathering all programs in one submenu in Kickoff Application Launcher

Tags: kubuntu, kickoff

Is there any easy way to put all programs in one submenu in Kickoff Application Launcher, instead of having been divided into different categories (development, education, games, graphics, internet, multimedia, office, science and math, settings system, utilities,…)?

I know that the can create a new submenu and manually copy and paste each program into it, but it's tedious. Is there any cleverer way?

[image]

Comment: The clever way is to use a launcher which has this option - the Homerun has it: http://i.imgur.com/8liOxeM.jpg . More KDE launchers: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?59851-KDE-Application-Launchers